# Validation Logic

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I am trying to create some validation for a form I have. There are two text boxes and two radio buttons on the form. My logic for this validation I know is a little rusty at the moment so any suggestions would be great.
Here is the code for what I have so far:

- Keep in mind that the int errors is a public variable in the class

Start Button code:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        errors = validateForm();

        //Here I want the user to be able to fix any errors  where I am little 
        stuck on that logic at the moment 

        //validate the form
        while (errors > 0)
        {
            validateForm();
            errors = validateForm();
        }
 }
```

ValidateForm Method:

```
 private int validateForm()
    {
        errors = 0; 

        //check the form if there are any unentered values
        if (txtDest.Text == "")
        {
            errors++;
        }
        if (txtExt.Text == "")
        {
            errors++;   
        }
        if (validateRadioBtns() == true)
        {
            errors++;
        }

        return errors;

    }
```

ValidateRadioBtns Method:

```
private Boolean validateRadioBtns()
    {
        //flag - false: selected, true: none selected
        Boolean blnFlag = false;

        //both of the radio buttons are unchecked
        if (radAll.Checked == false && radOther.Checked == false)
        {
            blnFlag = true;
        }
        //check if there is a value entered in the text box if other is checked
        else if(radOther.Checked == true && txtExt.Text == "")
        {
            blnFlag = true;
        }

        return blnFlag;
    }
```

Overall I feel like this can somehow be more stream lined which I am fairly stuck on.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated since I know this is such a nooby question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first since you have said that you want to validate for non-entered values, did you consider white spaces as an entry? since someone can just press space and then your validation would pass.

Aside from that, you might want to indicate which textbox they did not fill out or which group they did not click, it seems like you are using web forms so here is a walkthrough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100).aspx.

If you are using windows forms you can use this walkthrough http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx.

If you need to keep the existing logic, I would suggest extracting the repeating logic into separate functions and temporary btnFlag is not necessary also as you can return true and return false at the end.

```
private Boolean validateRadioBtns()
{
    if (radAll.Checked == false && radOther.Checked == false)
        return true;
    else if(radOther.Checked == true && txtExt.Text.Trim().Length == 0 ) //just a quick sample of how you can trim the spaces and check for length 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, i should have mentioned they are windows forms

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx) for the validation patterns. You have chosen the explicit validation strategy, for which you would use the [`ContainerControl.ValidateChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158374(v=vs.110).aspx) method and either perform your "Start" action or not.

Windows Forms has dedicated events for validation that allow you to react accordingly for each of your controls. You'll use [`Control.Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Control.Validated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

So, unless `ValidateChildren` returns `true`, you don't need to initiate your "Start" action, i.e. the logic would become trivial.

P.S. you also probably don't need the `errors` variable as a class member since you return it from your validation function. For showing the error, prefer the ["Tell, Don't Ask"](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) idea by separating the error visualization in a separate component.